# How to change color button no reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set of buttons:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <% @tables.each do |table| %>
        <%= button_to table.seats, service_path, method: :get, class: ["btn", "btn-primary", "btn-lg"], remote: true %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And I want to click a button and change its color without reloading the page.
The idea is to have a set of blue buttons and when click in one of them change its color to red.

Furthermore, set the session[:table] to the id of the `table` also without reloading the page.

-- Added --

Note: I ONLY WANT ONE RED BUTTON AT TIME.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
$(this).css({"background-color":"#00f"});
});
```

Comment: Hi @void, it doesn't work.. I debug in Chrome with a breakpoint in the first line and not enter in the second line. You know what happens?

Comment: Hi @void, I fixed with this code `$(function() {
  return $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#ff0000"});
  });
});` but it change the color of a button, but when I click another one it also change, I only want one red at time